# No consigo evaluar el valor de un QueryString (IF, SELEC CASE, etc) en una página ASP.NET con VB

Tags: android, asp.net, vb

Tengo una página ASP.NET con VB, la cual recibe en el QueryString desde una aplicación Android, varios parámetros para realizar algunos cálculos, por ejemplo:

```
    http://192.168.100.0:8080/pagina.aspx?med=120
```

En el code behind de la página:

```
    Dim strMedida As String = Request.QueryString("med")
```

Y si imprimo el valor de **strMedida**, me muestra el valor pasado en el request:

```
    Context.Response.Write("La medida es: " & strMedida)

    La medida es: 120
```

Pero al momento de evaluar la variable con un IF, un SELECT CASE, etc., para hacer alguna operación, no lo realiza. Ejemplo:

```
    Dim strRes as String
    Select Case strMedida
        Case "100"
            strRes = "La medida es Sencilla"
        Case "120"
            strRes = "La medida es Semi"
        Case "140"
            strRes = "La medida es Doble"
        Case Else
            strRes = "No hay medida"
    End Select
```

Y si imprimo el valor de **strRes**, me muestra como si **strMedida** no tuviera información. Lo mismo pasa si evalúo con **Request.QueryString("med")**:

```
    Context.Response.Write(strRes)

    No hay medida
```

Muchas gracias por su colaboración

Comment: El código está correcto, tu problema debe estar en otro lado